# C#: data from XML in DataGridView; how do I save edited rows?

Tags: xml, datagridview, save

I have a XML file, containing simple contact data from customers.

```
<ArrayOfCustomer>
<customer>
 <firstname>Joe</firstname>
 <lastname>Glenn</lastname>
 <fullname>Glenn, Joe</fullname>
 <email>joe.glenn@something.com</email>
 <substitude>mary.poppins@something.com</email>
 <language>EN</language>
</customer>
<customer>
 <firstname>Lionel</firstname>
 <lastname>Messi</lastname>
 <fullname>Messi, Lionel</fullname>
 <email>lionel.messi@something.com</email>
 <substitude>ernesto.valverde@something.com</substitude>
 <language>ES</language>
<customer>
<customer>...</customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

This data is displayed in a DataGridView inside a Windows Forms Element. This is done by deserialization and a BindingSource.
No problem so far.

Now I want that, whenever the data inside the DataGridView is edited (e.g., a customer is added, or an email adress is edited), these changes are saved to the XML file again.

Of course I could add a method, that is called at all changes. But I have the feeling, that this could be done much more easily. Can you please instruct me, how this can be done?

Also, I am very confused about all the terms DataBinding, DataSource, BindingSource, DataSet etc. and how they belong to each other. Can someone please sort that out for me?

Greetings and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how you are reading the XML file into the `DataGridView`, I will assume you are using an `XmlReader` and reading the file into a `DataSet` which in turn the `DataGridView` uses the first `DataTable` in this `DataSet` as a `DataSource`. If this is the case, then when the user edits or adds new info into the grid, these changes will be reflected in the `DataTable`.

Therefore, if you have the `DataTable` from the `DataGridView` and this `DataTable` belongs to a `DataSet`, you could use the `DataSet`’s .`WriteXml` method like below. This will write the `DataSet` to a properly formatted XML file.

Method to read the xml file and set the `dataGridView` `DataSource`

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

private void btn_ReadXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    using (XmlReader xmlFileToRead = XmlReader.Create("Customers.xml", new XmlReaderSettings())) {
      ds = new DataSet();
      ds.ReadXml(xmlFileToRead);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
      xmlFileToRead.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Then the method to write the xml file.

```
private void btn_SaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    using (XmlWriter xmlFileToWrite = XmlWriter.Create("Customers.xml", new XmlWriterSettings())) {
      ds.WriteXml(xmlFileToWrite);
      xmlFileToWrite.Close();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.